# How can I find out how many people are on my website with PHP

Tags: live, counter, visitor-pattern

I have a server and I want to make a control panel that has stats about who is connected to my website currently. How should I do this using PHP or Javascript?

Comment: if mod_status is installed you can obtain that information from http://localhost/server-status. PHP should be able to parse that.